# Wordpress - Attach uploaded image to post

Tags: php, image, post, wordpress

I'm using the Wordpress plugin [Alchimist Ajax Upload](https://wordpress.org/plugins/alchemist-ajax-upload/) to upload an image via Ajax, the post is created after submission of the form and after uploading the unattached images. My problem is that I need to attach those uploaded images to that created post. I have the post ID and the attachment ID, is there a php method that I could write to attach those two using just their IDs?
Thanks for any response I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't try it. But maybe you could use this. Got it from the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) in combination with the [get_attached_file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_file) function

```
// the ID of the attachment
$filename = get_attached_file( $attachment_id ); // Full path

// The ID of the post this attachment is for.
$parent_post_id = 37;

// Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

// Get the path to the upload directory.
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

// Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
$attachment = array(
  'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
  'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
  'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
  'post_content'   => '',
  'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

// Insert the attachment.
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );

// Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

// Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

Comment: Awesome, is there any way. if image exist then attache that image instead to upload same image once again?

Answer (score 1):

If you have **already uploaded attachment/media** and just want to "tie" it to the existing post, just set post_parent field of the attachment/media:

```
wp_update_post(
    array(
        'ID' => $attachment_id,
        'post_parent' => $post_id
    )
);
```